# Iterating over a list to find whether an element is greater than all following elements

Tags: python

I am currently stumped on trying to count the number of times each element of a list is greater than all it's following elements.

I have tried coding the solution with no luck with two examples. I want to be able to do this with two loops or one loop. Any thoughts in a brute force approach would be appreciated. This is what I have so far.

**Two Loops**

```
def count_dominators(items):
    count=0
    for i in range(len(items)):
        for j in range(len(items)-1):
                if items[j]>items[i]:
                    break
                if j == len(items)-1:
                    count+=1
        if i == len(items)-1:
            count+=1
    return count

items=[42, 7, 12, 9, 2, 5]
count_dominators(items)
```

**One Loop**

```
def count_dominators(items):
    count=0
    largest=items[-1]
    i=len(items)-1
    while i>=0:
        if items[i] > largest:
            count+=1
            i-=1
        return count
    
items=[42, 7, 12, 9, 2, 5]
print(count_dominators(items))
```

This is the assignment:

> ### Count dominators
>
> `def count_dominators(items):`
>
> An element of `items` is said to be a dominator if **every** element to
> its right (not just the one element that is immediately to its right)
> is strictly smaller than it. By this definition, the last item of the
> list is automatically a dominator. This function should count how may
> elements in `items` are dominators, and return that count. For example,
> the dominators of `[42, 7, 12, 9, 13, 5]` would be its elements `42`,
> `13`, and `5`.
>
> Before starting to write code for this funciton, you should consult the
> parable of "[Shlemiel the Painter](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm)" and think how this seemingly
> silly tale from a simpler time relates to today's computational
> problems performed on lists, strings and other sequences. This problem
> will be the first of many that you will encounter during and after this
> course to illustrate the important principle of using only one loop to
> achieve in a tiny fraction of time the same end result that Shlemiel
> achieves with two nested loops. Your workload therefore increases
> only **linearly** with respect to the number of `items`, whereas the
> total time of Shlemiel's back-and-forth grows **quadratically**, that
> is, as a function of the **square** of the number of items.
>
> | `items` | Expected result |
> | --- | --- |
> | `[42, 7, 12, 9, 2, 5]` | `4` |
> | `[]` | `0` |
> | `[99]` | `1` |
> | `[42, 42, 42, 42]` | `1` |
> | `range(10**7)` | `1` |
> | `range(10**7, 0, -1)` | `10000000` |
>
> Trying to hide the inner loop of some Shlemiel algortithm inside a
> function call (and this includes Python built-ins such as `max` and
> list slicing) and pretending that this somehow makes those inner loops
> take a constant time will only summon the Gods of Compubook Headings to
> return with tumult to claim their linon's share of execution time.

Comment: In your second example you are returning inside the loop. You are also only changing `i` inside the `if` block. This just seems like indenting issues. You should probably update the value of `largest` when you encounter a larger value too.

Comment: In addition to what @Mark mentioned, you should also initialize `largest` with `items[-1] - 1` (like in my answer below), it works in your example because you have a `7` in the list, replace that with `4` and you get 3 instead of 4.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your 2nd version refined (with comments on each change and fix):

```
def count_dominators(items):
    # - start with 1 smaller than last item
    # - handle empty list
    largest = items[-1] - 1 if items else 0
    count = 0

    # - use for loop
    # - use reversed(...)
    for item in reversed(items):
        if item > largest:
            count += 1
            # - update largest
            largest = item

    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over the naive solution first:

Consider an element at index `i` of the list. This element is a "dominator" if it is greater than all elements with index greater than `i`

```
def count_dominators(items):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(items)):
        is_dom = True # Assume for now that it is a dominator
        for j in range(i+1, len(items)):   # You only need elements after the ith element
            if items[i] <= items[j]: # If elem at i is less than j, this is not a dominator
                is_dom = False
                break   # So we don't need to check any more j for this i

        if is_dom: # Only increment the count if this is a dominator
            count += 1

    return count
```

This solution works in quadratic time.

Now for a smarter solution. I am not familiar with the parable of Shlemiel the painter, but an easy solution is to create another list, where the element at index `i` of this list is the maximum value of the sub-list `items[i+1:]`. Then, if the `i`th element of the original list is greater than the `i`th element of the new list, we know that it is a dominator. Since we don't want to hide the complexity in a `max()` call, we could iterate backwards over the list.

```
largest_vals = [0] * len(items)

largest_vals[-1] = items[-1] - 1  

largest = items[-1]
for index in range(len(items)-2, -1, -1): # Iterate backwards
    if items[index] > largest:
        largest = items[index]

    largest_vals[index] = largest
```

Next, iterate over the list regularly, and count how many elements are greater than their corresponding `largest_vals`:

```
count = 0
for elem, lv in zip(items, largest_vals):
    if elem > lv:
        count += 1
```

As a function:

```
def count_dominators(items):
    if not items: return 0

    largest_vals = [0] * len(items)
    
    largest_vals[-1] = items[-1] - 1  # To handle the case of the last element 
    
    largest = items[-1]
    for index in range(len(items)-2, -1, -1): # Iterate backwards from the second-to-last element to the first

        if items[index+1] > largest: # Only overwrite largest if the current element is bigger
            largest = items[index+1]
    
        largest_vals[index] = largest 

    count = 0
    for elem, lv in zip(items, largest_vals):
        if elem > lv:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Of course, you can simplify this into a single loop by simply checking that `items[index] > largest` in the original loop, but it helps to visualize the problem if you separate them out.

To test this:

```
ls = [([42,7,12,9,2,5], 4), ([], 0), ([99], 1), ([42, 42, 42, 42], 1), (list(range(10**7)), 1), (list(range(10**7, 0, -1)), 10**7)]

for input_val, expected_val in ls:
    print(count_dominators(input_val), expected_val)
```

Which shows that the function returns the expected value for all the test cases

```
4 4
0 0
1 1
1 1
1 1
10000000 10000000
```

Comment: *"I am not familiar with the parable of Shlemiel the painter"* - Just something popularized by [someone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) who never created anything you've used :-P

Answer (score 1):

Going backwards like you tried and how Shlomo did is best. If you *can* go backwards. Here's an alternative that works when you *can't*, i.e., when you have an iterable that you can only iterate forwards.

```
def count_dominators(items):
    doms = []
    for item in items:
        while doms and item >= doms[-1]:
            doms.pop()
        doms.append(item)
    return len(doms)
```

I keep a (decreasing) list of dominators of the items seen so far. For example if that's `[56, 13, 2]` and then I see `41`, that removes the `2` and `13` from the dominators before being appended as the new dominator-by-default. The dominators list then is `[56, 41]`.

Runtime is O(n). You might think *"But it has two nested loops, didn't the assignment just tell me that that takes quadratic time?"*. Well, no, not this kind of nested loops. The inner loop pops an item, and since we *append* each item only once, we also *pop* each item at most once. So *overall*, the inner loop runs at most n times.